# Как при клике на UI кнопку вызвать методы скрипта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я делаю главное меню для игры по видеоролику из ютуба. После того как рассказчик написал скрипты для кнопок — он стал добавлять их в эти кнопки. Я этого сделать по какой-то причине не могу. Я не могу добавить ни старт гейм, ни выход. У меня этого просто нет. В видео отображается контекстное меню и последняя строчка с названием `NewBehaviourScript`. У меня ее нет.

Подскажите как ее добавить? Я уже обыскал весь ютуб, гугл и сайт юнити, но так и не смог найти решение своей проблемы. Скрипт написан на *C#*.

Comment: А куда Вы её собираетесь добавить?

Comment: В низу компонента Button там где On Click, место No Function

Comment: Мне туда нужно поставить NewBehaviourScript. Но в появляющемся контекстом меню такого нет.

Answer (score 10):

В *UI* у кнопок можно назначить событие `OnClick`.

Например есть кнопки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В их свойствах **кнопки** находим `OnClick`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нем нужно выбрать объект, **на котором висит скрипт-обработчик** (это может быть и сама кнопка, при желании), а затем в правой части этого выпадающего списка выбрать тот самый скрипт и нужный метод из того самого скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё.

Причем методы должны быть **публичными**. Пример:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchCameras : MonoBehaviour {

    private void Start() {

    }

    public void Switch() {
        Debug.Log("Тут какой-то метод вызывался");
    }
}
```

При появлении метода с аргументами - в событии `OnClick` кнопки можно будет добавить этот самый параметр:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ

Comment: @Радомир Лучше маленький рублик, чем большое спасибо. Для этого здесь есть "стрелка вверх", если вы находите ответ полезным, и галочкой вы, как автор вопроса,  можете отметить ответ как правильный.

Comment: Так я только что зарегался просто

Comment: @Радомир о. тут что-то происходит в комментах а я и не в курсе)) ммм... ну теперь точно можешь жмакать галку, если помог ответ

Comment: @Радомир, почему ещё не поставил галочку правильного ответа?!))

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev он заходил последний раз 26.03.2018 :D