# Скрипт почему-то работает по всей сцене.Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Решил создать пробное меню уровней( только начал разбирать Unity). И столкнулся с странной проблемой.
Скрипт который я прикрепил к обьекту работает по всей сцене.
Создал сцену с двумя обьектами, при нажатии на один должен запускаться 1-й уровень, а при нажатии на другой 2-й, соответственно. Но по итогу куда бы я не нажал переключается на уровень.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;
public class levelScript : MonoBehaviour
{

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```

}

Collider к обьекту прикрепил. Так же на всякий случай пробовал и через Application.LoadLevel.

Comment: А как, по-вашему, должен загрузиться второй уровень вот тут `SceneManager.LoadScene(0);` ?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что код, загружают единственную сцену будет загружать разные сцены?

Comment: Для "Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)" не нужно ни коллайдеров, ни кнопок интерфейса. Ничего, кроме активного скрипта на сцене. При любом нажатии на левую кнопку мыши условие в активном/включенном скрипте "levelScript" будет выполнено и последует выполнение команды "SceneManager.LoadScene(0);"

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/670937/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ui-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0) есть подробная инструкция, как можно работать с кнопками и действиями по нажатию на них

Comment: Вам следует либо изучить кнопки (Button), по ссылке, данной @Анастасия, либо посмотреть на [BoxCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html) и функции OnMouseDown

Comment: @АлексейШиманский
Это я прекрасно понимаю, но проблема то кроилась не в этом, по этому и убрал все лишнее.

Comment: @МаксимФисман
Это я прекрасно понимаю, но проблема то кроилась не в этом, по этому и убрал все лишнее.

Comment: Попробуйте переименовать кнопки уровней в цифры "1, 2, 3..." и использовать `gameobject.name` для получения номера уровня, дальше `int.Parse(gameobject.name")` подставить вместо 0 в функции `LoadScene`

Answer (score 0):

`Создал сцену с двумя объектами` - повесьте на них компонент Button.

В вашем скрипте должен быть подобный код:

```
public void OnClick (int targetSceneNum) {
    SceneManager.LoadScene(targetSceneNum);
}
// ИЛИ
public void OnClick (string targetScene) {
    SceneManager.LoadScene(targetScene);
}
```

Цепляете этот скрипт куда-нибудь.  В Button для всех кнопок нажимаете +, указываете этот объект, выбираете этот метод, задаете свой параметр для каждой кнопки - номер (или имя) сцены, куда эта кнопка должна направлять.

Comment: @Ars Если мой ответ был вам полезен, пожалуйста, примите его, нажав галочку. Если у вас есть вопросы или недопонимания, или что-то не работает, вы можете написать об этом в комментариях под вашим вопросом или моим ответом, чтобы вам могли помочь разобраться.